# What is ArrayBuffer equivalent to readUInt32BE node's method?

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer, webauthn

`readUInt32BE` method reads an unsigned, big-endian 32-bit integer from buf at the specified offset.

```js
import { Buffer } from 'node:buffer';

const buf = Buffer.from([0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78]);

console.log(buf.readUInt32BE(0).toString(16));
// Prints: 12345678
```

https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#bufreaduint32beoffset

Please, help to get the same value with `ArrayBuffer` without node.js.

Comment: Uh, if you're using node.js `Buffer`s, then why don't you want to use their methods?!

Comment: I use Deno and ArrayBuffer, do not have node.js

Comment: What do you mean by "ES6" and "vanilla JS", or what part of that do you think _isn't_ those things? Do you really mean in a non-Node environment, e.g. a browser?

Comment: @korywka Then please mention that in your question

Comment: For array buffers, use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView/getUint32

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, can you please write answer? I will fix my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with an `ArrayBuffer` of a typed array, you'd create a [`DataView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) on it to use the [`getUint32` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView/getUint32):

```
const buffer = Uint8Array.from([0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78]).buffer;
const LE = true, BE = false;

console.log(new DataView(buffer).getUint32(0, BE).toString(16)); // 12345678
```

Using a `Uint32Array` as a view is potentially faster (in bulk), but does not guarantee a specific endianness.

Comment: I **knew** there was a simpler way to create and populate that array.